# Moving h1 to be at the bottom of a div

Tags: css

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG0hE.png)

So I was wondering what is the best way or optimal way of getting the desired result in the [Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYdnw.png)

The two ways I think it is possible with my current css knowledge, is through making the containing div have a static height or by getting the h1 element be positioned at the bottom of the div.

So what I was wondering is what css properties I should be looking at and a preferred method of getting my desired result.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Ohk, cool I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to align the background with the baseline you can do that with a pseudo element.

```css
h2::before, h1::before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2em;
    background: gray;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
h2{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>A title with some CAPS and some gg's</h1>
<h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
```

Comment: Cool thank you just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you are looking for:

1. Set div's static height and position h1 absolute at the bottom.
2. Let h1 define div's height by using padding.

```css
.test1 {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.test1 h1 {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.test2 {
  background-color: grey;
}
.test2 h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <h1>Testing</h1>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="test2">
  <h1>Testing</h1>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7uax3pa5/2/

Comment: Note that your result has grey underneath the h1 which is probably cause by line-height (and possily descenders). This may be partially overcome by only using block capitals but you would have to test.

Comment: Yes, greyish line may be "removed" by setting a lower `line-height` value or using negative `bottom` value.

Comment: Yes, but the value of the line-height  / margin would be **font-dependent**...not all fonts have the same spacing. - See - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ojMbYb

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, you need to just
`vertical-align:bottom` and `display:table-cell` in element (`h1`).

```css
h1{
 background:#333;
 color:#fff;
 height:50px;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 display:table-cell;
 width:500px;
}
```

```html
<h1>text</h1>
```

I hope it will helps you.